# GParted tells me my partition has 1.30 GiB used space but I cannot access its contents

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-10.04, gparted

I've a ext4 partition (`/dev/sda7`) for my Linux. And, another (`/dev/sda5`) for keeping my data. When I installing Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, I set the mount point of `/dev/sda5` to "`/`" and that of `/dev/sda5` to "`/data`". GParted tells me that 1.30 GiB out of 70.12 GiB of `/dev/sda5` has been used up. But, the mounted directory "`/data`" is empty. So, it looks like that my data is there but I cannot access it. Besides, when I set the mount point, I didn't check the "format" box. So, it shouldn't have been formatted. How can I check whether the partition has been formatted? How can I recover my files?

Comment: a listing of your partition table and sda entries from /etc/fstab would be most helpful

Answer (score 1):

I believe I read somewhere that you have to allow sharing between the partitions. And perhaps a screen shot of where you're looking that says your data is not there would be helpful. Also, under applications on the menu bar, their is a disk usage analyzer which allows you to look at each drive, mount/unmount, format, edit, check for errors, etc. If this doesn't work and you have no data you want to keep on those drives, just try reinstalling Ubuntu 10.5 and redo your partitioning tables.

Hope this helps!! =)